# Get data from collection between hours of each day in c#

Tags: c#

I have a collection that contains lots of data, and timestamp in this data is some define time steps for example 10 minutes.

now i need to group it in very special way. That is each record has a timestamp and I need to group this in something like for each day data between hours.
For example I need a data between

```
2023.05.01 00:10:00 and 2023.05.02 00:00:00
2023.05.02 00:10:00 and 2023.05.03 00:00:00
```

and so on.

I managed to group it by day:

```
var batchGroupedByDay = 
    batch
    .GroupBy(value => new { year = value.Timestamp.Year, month = value.Timestamp.Month, day = value.Timestamp.Day });
```

But it is not what I am aiming for, and no idea where to go next.

Comment: What do you want to happen to any items within the first 10 minutes of the day, e.g. 2023-05-02T00:05:00? (That isn't in either of the groups that you listed - it's between them.)

Comment: non existent, data is split in defined time steps for example as above 10 minutes

Comment: "it is not what I am aiming for" why not? It seems to cover all cases. Although you could shorten it to `var batchGroupedByDay = batch.GroupBy(value => value.Timestamp.Date)`

Comment: Well because if Ill group it by day ill miss that midnight record next day

Comment: `var batchGroupedByDay = batch.GroupBy(value => value.Timestamp.AddSeconds(-1).Date)` then

Comment: "data is split in defined time steps for example as above 10 minutes" - it's really not clear what you mean. Please put more time into clarifying the requirements. (If it so happens that you'll never get any data between midnight and 00:10, then you're just grouping by date, right? That isn't a "very special way".)

Comment: You should also ask yourself whether those start and end times are inclusive or exclusive. Normally start times are inclusive and end times are exclusive. Is that the case here? Specify it in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ticks to do the grouping

```
            List<Batch> batch = new List<Batch>();
            long tenMinutes = 10 * TimeSpan.TicksPerMinute; 
            var batchGroupedByDay =
              batch.OrderBy(x => x.Timestamp)
              .GroupBy(value => value.Timestamp.Ticks / tenMinutes);
```

Comment: "You only want time after 10:00 AM" - I don't think that's the case.

Comment: @JonSkeet : look at the sample times.  The OP wants BETWEEN.

Comment: I'm looking at the sample times - and I'm looking at them closely. There's nothing about 10am there. 10am is 10:00:00, not 00:10:00. So where are you getting "You only want time after 10:00 AM" from?

Comment: @JonSkeet : I was reading hour instead of minutes

Answer (score 0):

This should group by any `TimeSpan` (as long as it's not smaller than one second), starting from any start date. If you, for example, want to group by day starting at 11am, you'd call it with something like `GroupByTimeSpan(mySource, TimeSpan.FromHours(24), DateTime.MinValue.AddHours(11))`

```
static Dictionary<TimeSpan, List<YourObj> GroupByTimeSpan(YourObj[] source, TimeSpan timespan, DateTime startDate) 
{
    var result = new Dictionary<TimeSpan, List<YourObj>();
    var duration = (long)timespan.TotalSeconds;

    foreach (var element in source) 
    {
        var timediff = (long)(element.timestamp - startDate).TotalSeconds;
        var key = new TimeSpan(timediff / duration);

        if (result.TryGetValue(key, out var list)) list.Add(element);
        else result.Add(key, new List<YourObj>() { element});
    }

    return result;
}
```